# rails 3.1 db:test:prepare and "pending migrations" problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, migration

Recent switch to Rails 3.1.0.rc4, and I'm having trouble getting our CI builds to run.  It boils down to the following simplified case:

```
-bash-3.2$ echo $RAILS_ENV
test
-bash-3.2$ bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:test:prepare
You have 21 pending migrations:
  20100628174219 InitialSchema
  20100706175001 AddCompanyToClassifieds
  20100720132917 CartItemActionMigration
  20100811192506 AddJobTitleToDirectoryListings
  ...
```

If I replace that command with `bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare` it works fine.

In digging deeper the core `db:test:prepare` task has `db:abort_if_pending_migrations` as a pre-requisite.

Now am I just missing something obvious, or is that completely pointless?  Running `db:test:prepare` (in the standard case) calls `db:schema:load` which executes schema.rb -- whose entire point is to load the schema without running all migrations.  By failing to run unless all migrations have been executing (thus forcing a `db:migrate` prior to `db:test:prepare`), does it not make itself utterly useless?

I guess I can add the extra `db:migrate` to my CI build process, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `db:test:prepare` is not intended to run in the TEST environment (otherwise you could just run `db:schema:load` yourself).  Normally you would run `db:test:prepare` in the development environment.  The check for pending migrations is then quite useful (you will know if your coworkers committed some new migrations before you run and fail a bunch of tests).  Since running the tests runs `db:test:prepare` *anyway*, you should rarely need to run that by hand (certainly not for your CI builds).  Omit the call to `db:test:prepare`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not manually calling <code>db:test:prepare</code> -- it's a pre-req of <code>rake spec</code>.  I just listed it above manually to simplify the problem.  <code>rake spec</code> is supposed to be run in the test env, so I have a hard time imagining that <code>db:test:prepare</code> is intended for development env only.  (In fact, I would never use it in development mode as it would destroy my data.)  Again, thank you for the reply.

Comment: @David mcCullars: Read through `activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake`, `db:test:prepare` would never destroy your development data, and is not intended to be run in the development environment (the tasks in the `test` namespace operate on the `test` database).  I can't speak for the `spec` task as I do not use it, but it sounds like it shouldn't be run in the test environment either.